# Change font of document title

Tags: fonts, fontspec, titles

I have used fontspec to style all of my headers with a new font with:

```
% Specify different font for section headings
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Gill Sans}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\headingfont}
```

Now I want to style my document title to use Gill Sans as well since it would match the style of the rest of the document. How do I do this?

Comment: It depends on the class used: KoMa classes probably have their method for managing the font for the title, the standard classes don't.

The solution depends also on what you want precisely: only the title or the whole title block?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the standard document classes you can use the [`titling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Specify different font for section headings
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Gill Sans}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\headingfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}
\author{An author}
\title{The title of the article}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 6):

I am a beginner with LaTeX. This answer helped me change the font type of the sections. But it did not change the font type of the title to match that of the sectioning. It was not so obvious to me, so I am putting the answer.

It turned out all I had to do is the following:

```
\title{\headingfont {The title of the article} }
```

Comment: This will probably do what you want, but it has unintended consequences.  The `\title` command is for declaring the *title of the document*.   The document title is `The title of the article`, not `\headingfont{The title of the article}`.  Anything that looks at the content of `\title` (e.g., `hyperref`) will be confused or complain.

Answer (score 2):

`fontspec` package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please, be more specific since it doesn't seem to answer the question.