# How to change the font for chapter title with titlesec and titling under XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, titlesec, titling

I'm using `XeTeX` to edit a document in which I am trying to use `titlesec` and `titling` to set a different font for some headings.

I'm using the approach suggested as a [reply to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/change-font-of-document-title), but so far my success is really partial.

The `section` and `subsection` titles change the font as desired, but the `chapter` title ignores the setting.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
%%% to allow custom headings
\usepackage{titlesec}
% to change titles font family
\usepackage{titling}


%%% declare fonts and set some formats
% fontspec to use non-latex with xetex
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

% font declaration and title settings
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Armata}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}
```

The chapter setting is something I tried while mimicking the solution provided in the link above. I learnt that removing the `*` is required somehow as the `easy mode` would not work with chapter titles. I didn't find why, yet. But truth is that removing the asterisk also gets rid of the error... but it doesnt seem to work regarding the font face setting.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Edit: I found a really silly error, that led me to a (partial) solution and a new error showing up. I just set `\documentclass{book}` and now the renderer tries to put the desired font, but `titlesec` throws an error:

`Titles must not be nested`

The LaTeX code is this:

```
\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}

The title above does not show any font.

\section{First Section}

Works as desired.

\subsection{Subsection}

Hiya! This also shows up as expected.

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

We have not declared a titleformat for this heading, and so it is shown with the default font.

\section{Second section}

Repeating the success

\end{document}
```

The `chapter` title is the one that triggers the titlesec error.

Comment: Have you tried using `sectsty` instead of `titlesec` - I haven't used the latter, but I found `sectsty` quite easy to use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The line

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\LARGE\headingfont}
```

is the culprit. The syntax is wrong. The right one is

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge\headingfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

So, the MWE (I've used Arial instead of Armata since I don't have that font installed):

```
\documentclass{book}
%%% to allow custom headings
\usepackage{titlesec}
% to change titles font family
\usepackage{titling}


%%% declare fonts and set some formats
% fontspec to use non-latex with xetex
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

% font declaration and title settings
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Arial}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge\headingfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}
\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}

The title above does not show any font.

\section{First Section}

Works as desired.

\subsection{Subsection}

Hiya! This also shows up as expected.

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

We have not declared a titleformat for this heading, and so it is shown with the default font.

\section{Second section}

Repeating the success

\end{document}
```

yields the following output

[image]