# How to change Chapter font

Tags: font-encodings, calligra

Is there a different way than in [How to change the font for chapter title with titlesec and titling under XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167859/how-to-change-the-font-for-chapter-title-with-titlesec-and-titling-under-xetex/) to change chapter font, one that uses a T1 font. I am starting from this code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

The title above does not show any font.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any packages you might alter the definition of `\@makechapterhead`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
  \vspace*{50\p@}
  {%
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \sffamily% or whatever you want here
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge \bfseries \@chapapp \space \thechapter \par
        \nobreak \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty \@M \Huge \bfseries #1\par
    \nobreak \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

The title above does not show any font.

\end{document}
```

You could as well use the package `titlesec` or something similar. If you want that, it also has many features to further customize the looking of headings.

**EDIT:** If you want to use the calligra-fonts you'll have to use `\calligra` instead of `\sffamily` like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
  \vspace*{50\p@}
  {%
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \calligra% or whatever you want here
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge \bfseries \@chapapp \space \thechapter \par
        \nobreak \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty \@M \Huge \bfseries #1\par
    \nobreak \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

The title above does not show any font.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, where do i change the font ?  I tried  `\fmmfamily% or whatever you want here`, `\arial` and `\calligra` but it didnt work.

Comment: @alfred `\calligra` does work. If you want Arial you'll have to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and the `fontspec` package. But I can't help you with that, since I never used them. I'll update my answer to use Calligra.

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid. I had written `\Calligra`. But when I try `\fmmfamily` after `\usepackage{miama}` for Miama Nueva it compiles, but doesnt create a pdf.

Comment: @alfred I get the following error for `miama`: "Font miama-t1 at 746 not found". I guess I can't help you because the font is not installed on my machine :)