# Format heading and subheading

Tags: sectioning, lyx

I'm working with LyX (class: report) and have tried to make the headlines more appealing. This also works partly, but I would like to improve some details and can't get any further after some trial and error. Therefore I am glad about every help.

This is my LaTeX opening in LyX:

```
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{RoyalRed}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Large\bfseries}
```

This is the result:
[image: Current output]

I would like to display the chapter and subchapters (including the numbers) uniformly with the font Arial. I've never defined a font explicitly (the chapter font is preset, I'm not sure if it's actually Arial). I would also like to change the color of the chapter number to "RoyalRed".

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I'm afraid there would be conflicts between `fncychap` and `titlesec`, so the only solution might be to patch the Bjornstrup style. Could post a small compilable code of what you've tried?

Comment: Hello and many thanks for the answer! I don't know LaTeX very well and therefore use Lyx. I just found an error in my code: in the last line, it should read thesection and not thechapter (the problem is nevertheless not solved)

What I tried is (as far as I remember) the following: I defined

\usepackageage{fontspec} 
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont[]{Arial}

(after https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/change-font-of-document-title), and then integrated \headingfont or \sectionfont[]  into {\...\bfseries}. This has caused a fatal error.

Comment: It's impossible to help without a minimal (yet complete) code reproducing the error..